# Спрайты для Unity3D

Tags: unity3d

В Photoshop сделал 2D дорогу размером 8000х4000 пикселей и сохранил в png разрешение стоит 300 пикс/дюйм. Когда кидаю спрайт на сцену и смотрю как он будет выглядеть в игре, то качество оставляет желать лучшего (на картинке как выглядит). Каких размеров нужно делать спрайты, чтобы они качественно смотрелись на сцене и в игре?

[image: unit]

Comment: Вероятно, у вас в настройках спрайта в Инспекторе стоит "галочка" `Advanced -> Generate Mip Maps`

Comment: Возможно, что вы решили проблему вообще не тем способом. Я вижу, что дорога у вас повторяющаяся, поэтому можно сделать текстуру одного сегмента дороги, а **Sprite Renderer - Draw Mode** поставить **Tiled**. Таким образом вы избежите хранения в ОЗУ огромной текстуры.

Comment: @trollingchar А где находится окно Sprite Renderer?

Comment: @Alt_F4 это компонент, находится на игровом объекте, а виден из панели инспектора, когда объект выделен.

Comment: @trollingchar при изменении меняется всё, или только этот спрайт. И если только этот спрайт, то тогда как менять все сразу.

Comment: @Alt_F4 меняется только этот спрайт. Чтобы менять все сразу, нужно сделать объект префабом.

Comment: Дорога может и не повторяться. Я эффектом "Волна" пока что для тестов сделал такую дорогу, но в будущем хочу сделать всю дорогу разнообразной по максимуму.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

1. `Format` должен быть на `RGBA 32bit`.
2. А `Max Size` должен быть на самом высоком размере.

**Внимание**: То что я говорил не проверено опытом, но так советуют в [документации](https://docs.unity3d.com/ru/current/Manual/class-TextureImporter.html) и в других сайтах.

Comment: Я бы сам хотел узнать результат. После проверки пожалуйста сообщите мне - был ли я прав?

Comment: Max Size точно влияет, картинка сжимается если она была больше. Pixels Per Unit - просто масштабирующий коэффициент и не влияет на качество.

Comment: @trollingchar спасибо. Я сейчас исправлю ответ

Comment: Спасибо. Понял. Только одно уточнение, а какой Pixels Per Unit обычно указывают, чтобы спрайт был масштабом 100%?

Comment: @Kolhoznik PixelsPerUnit означает сколько пикселей придется на одну единицу пространства. Если указать 1, один пиксель спрайта будет соответствовать 1 единице пространства. По умолчанию стоит 100, что даст спрайт в 100 раз мельче. Это просто коэффициент масштабирования и он ничего не сожмет и не размылит.

Comment: понял, спасибо.

Comment: @Kolhoznik только пожалуйста в следующий раз обращайтесь с помощью знака "@", как я. А то либо все получают уведомление, либо никто не получает.